# Google sign-in with Firebase and Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-signin

I am stuck with this for a while now and i have no ideas left.

I use Google Sign-In (`package: google_sign_in`) with Flutter and this is the issue.

The problem is that Google Sign-In works perfectly in Android debug mode, IOS debug/release mode. But when i add it to Google Play Store. It stops working without giving a clear error. (Used `Logcat` and `Sentry` to find something that could help me)

**These are the things i did without any luck:**

1. Used the debug and release SHA1 and also checked Google Playstore App Sign and added both SHA1 certificates
2. Checked all the API keys in Google Cloud Console to see if the API credentials matches the certificates
3. Got verified on OAuth consent screen with the domain that also is verified
4. Added support email address in Firebase
5. Tripple checked the google-services.json and uploaded it inside `android/app/`
6. "Cleaned" Flutter to the point it is spotless

Did i missed something?